# Dynamic numeric access key in listview WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, keyboard-shortcuts, access-keys

i have a listview, and i want each listviewitem to have an associated numeric access key. So that when the access key is used, the listviewitem is toggling IsSelected.

also i do not want the numeric access key to be part of some label on the listviewitem, but instead i want the access key to pop onscreen, as in outlook:[image: outlook access key]

Is this possible in WPF?

```
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <ToggleButton x:Name="tb" Visibility="Hidden" IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListViewItem}, Path=IsSelected}"/>
                    <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                           Target="{Binding ElementName=tb}"
                           Content="_1" />
                    <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            Content="ItemName" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

this works for the toggling of IsSelected, but the rest is questionmark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using KeyTipService.KeyTip = "1"

and then some codebehind by listening to KeyTipAccessed

then you can press Alt + 1 and run the logic you want in codebehind